# Is it possible to get a noise texture spilling out of the mesh borders?

Tags: mesh, shaders, shader-nodes

**So I have this base cylindrical mesh with a noise shader on it.**

[image: My base shape with a noise texture]

As you can see the noise is constrained because of the bounds of the mesh.

**Is there any way that I can make the noise come out of the mesh so it doesn't look cut off.
Kind of like the mesh is radiating that noise texture.**

Example below image.

[image: Example of how I want it to be]

Comment: No, you can't add textures to the absence of geometry. You always do the opposite, make the mesh bigger, then mask parts of the texture around the borders you don't want.

Comment: how can I mask the parts of the texture ? kind of a blender noobie here

Comment: Search is your friend Here is a technique for blurring edges https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131184/how-to-make-the-edges-of-an-object-blur-to-alpha and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55991/blurring-feathering-a-procedural-pointiness-mask

Answer (score 3):

A mask is a black and white image that tells a mix shader "which parts go where" when mixing two other textures (or materials). Here is an example of one I made by warping a spherical gradient with a noise texture:

[image: Mask1]

When using this as a mix factor between the colored noise you already have and a Transparent shader, only the desired part is shown, and the rest is transparent, or "masked off" if you will. Remember to switch to your blend mode alpha-blend if you are using EEVEE for the transparency to show properly.

[image: Mask2]