# How to blur edges of a mesh using a shader node setup?

Tags: node-editor, edges, shader-nodes, blur

I saw [this node set up](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131184/how-to-make-the-edges-of-an-object-blur-to-alpha) on how to blur the edges of a mesh. I also set up the same nodes, but my result is not the same. What am I doing incorrectly?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In Eevee you need to change the alpha blend mode to make sure it is supported

Comment: Would have been nice to include the original post https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131184/how-to-make-the-edges-of-an-object-blur-to-alpha Also, even with @Gorgious (correct) hint, the node setup will not blur the edges of a sphere, it creates a radial fade texture starting from the object's origin (note the object is a plane in the original image). Not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: @Gergious, thanks!